# Getting a "Suspension function con only be called..." error with flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I am trying to get some knowledge in reactive programming and working with flows, so I took a method out of my contact class and tried to rewrite it a bit and use a flow to emit the data

```kotlin
val getMCxContactsFlow: Flow<MCxContact> = flow {
        val contact: MCxContact? = null
        val uri = RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
            .appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
            .build()

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(
            uri,
            arrayOf(Contacts._ID),
            null,
            null,
            null
        )
        getCursorInformation(cursor) { result ->
            result.apply {
                try {
                    val id = getStringOrNull(getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID))
                        ?: throw Exception("Cant find contact ID")
                    Log.d(TAG, id)
                    val query = contentResolver.query(
                        Data.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        "${Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID} =?",
                        arrayOf(id),
                        null
                    )
                    val contacts = getContactFromQuery(query)
                    emit(contacts) // The Emit with the Error
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        emit(contact!!) //This emit with the fake contact from first line works
    }

    private fun getCursorInformation(
        cursor: Cursor?,
        iterator: (cursor: Cursor) -> Unit
    ) {
        if (cursor == null) throw Exception("getCursorInformation: cursor is null")
        else {
            cursor.apply {
                if (count > 0) {
                    while (moveToNext()) iterator(this)
                } else {
                    throw Exception("Cursor data is empty")
                }
                close()
            }
        }
    }
```

But Android gives me an Error on emit: `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body`
The emit on the end does work without any error. So I assume there is a scope Problem. But what exactly is wrong here?

Comment: is `getCursorInformation(cursor)` method suspendable ? If not, it "breaks" coroutine scope propagation, which means that emit cannot be called from within it.

Comment: @amanin thanks for the comment! I appended the method above. When I make it suspendable, it makes no difference. but I think i know whats happening, since the bloack where the emit is in, is basically an anonymous function of getCursorInformation and therefore it does not work. but how can i lift it out and still emitting data?

Comment: I cannot find it in official documentation, but I think that lambda can also be marked suspendable. Have you tried replacing `iterator: (cursor: Cursor) -> Unit` argument with `iterator: suspend (cursor: Cursor) -> Unit` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user @amanin
The solution is to make the callback `iterable()` function also suspendable

```kotlin
   private suspend fun getCursorInformation(
        cursor: Cursor?,
        iterator: suspend (cursor: Cursor) -> Unit
    ) {
        if (cursor == null) throw Exception("getCursorInformation: cursor is null")
        else {
            cursor.apply {
                if (count > 0) {
                    while (moveToNext()) iterator(this)
                } else {
                    throw Exception("Cursor data is empty")
                }
                close()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To emit flow values from inside a callback like this, you should use a `callbackFlow`. Just replace `flow { ... }` with `callbackFlow { ... }` and replace `emit` with `send` (or `sendBlocking`, if necessary).

You might also need to add something like `awaitClose` to make sure the flow remains open while the callback is still active. Check [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) for more instructions on how to set up a callback flow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately this does not work

Comment: This answer should have worked.. what problem are you facing now @ChrisPi

Comment: @BugsHappen It says the same error as on `emit()`